# How to return multiple values in scope.watch?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-watch

I am trying to return multiple values from $scope.watch function.

```
angular.module("MainApp")
.directive('isActiveNav', [ '$location', function($location) {
    return {
     restrict: 'A',
     link: function($scope, el, attrs) {
      $scope.location = $location;
      $scope.$watch(function() {
              return (el.parent().parent().parent().parent().hasClass('cbp-small'),location.path());
          }, function(hasClas, currentPath) {
              setTimeout(function(){
                console.log(hasClas, currentPath);
             },0)
        });
    }
 };
}]);
```

But this is giving me this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode`.

**I am trying to watch multiple values here:
 1. Current-Url of the APP
 2. If a certain element has a class named "cbp-small"**

I have tried $watchCollection and $watchGroup also but weren't able to make them work either. And thus am trying to return multiple values form scope.watch func.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument will not accept a two values in `( )` syntax. Instead you want to store both values you want to watch and return in either an object or an array.

```
angular.module("MainApp")
.directive('isActiveNav', [ '$location', function($location) {
    return {
     restrict: 'A',
     link: function($scope, el, attrs) {
      $scope.location = $location;
      $scope.$watch(
        function() {
          return {hasPath: el.parent().parent().parent().parent().hasClass('cbp-small'), currentPath: location.path()};
        }, 
        function(newPathObject, oldPathObject) {
          if (!angular.equals(newPathObject, oldPathObject)) {
            setTimeout(function(){               
              console.log(newPathObject.hasClass, newPathObject.currentPath);
            },0)
          };
        },
        true
      });
     }
   };
}]);
```

You also want to add `true` as a third argument for objectEquality == true. According to [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope):

> When objectEquality == true, inequality of the watchExpression is determined according to the angular.equals function. To save the value
>   of the object for later comparison, the angular.copy function is used.
>   This therefore means that watching complex objects will have adverse
>   memory and performance implications.

Also, when working with $watch, you want to prevent the callback from triggering upon instansiation of the object by wrapping it in an `if` statement and checking if the object values have changed with `angular.equals`. You can reference this using [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1F346bXq2Xqqqat6mJyY?p=preview).

Comment: it will call callback every time, because objects are stored by reference, dirtycheck will always  pass

Comment: arrays are objects :)) so it will be working as well that way

Comment: You can pass `true` as the third parameter of `$scope.$watch` to make AngularJS use `angular.equals` instead of `==` for dirty checking. Then this solution is the best one, I think.

Comment: Well the first time it will, but you can check if object has been modified. @stevuu ah yes!! Thats right I forgot the true argument.

Comment: You can remove the `!angular.equals` part if you use the `true` parameter, because AngularJS does that for you.

Comment: Feel free to test it.

Comment: Am making a plnkr at the moment to test it lol. I'll clean up the logic once I've verified.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov is correct atleast according to the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1F346bXq2Xqqqat6mJyY?p=preview) I have made. Feel free to double check.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate values:

```
return el.parent().parent().parent().parent().hasClass('cbp-small').toString() + "&&&" + location.path();
```

So then will be generated a string like `"true&&&/.../.../"`
Angular will dirty check this string, if any of values will change that string will change so callback will be invoked
and in callback write

```
function(newVal) {
     var args = newVal.split('&&&');
     var hasClas = args[0]==="true", currentPath = args[1];
     setTimeout(function(){
         console.log(hasClas, currentPath);
     },0
});
```